# Linear Algebra:If a matrix is singular,is it true that also has linearly dependent rows/columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a matrix comes up to be singular,that means that the equations that were in the matrix are actually related/dependent,which means that the system can't yet be solved.So,if one proves that a matrix is singular,it is safe to say that the rows(equations) are dependent(?).On the other hand,can also one say that the columns are dependent too?Because if u and v are vectors(columns of the matrix) then their relation would be u=kv,where k is a real number.So,in the end,a singular matrix doesn't only imply that the system cannot be solved just yet(or at all),but also that the fault of that is because the equations picked to represent the matrix were linerly dependent (like the equations x+y=2 <=> 2x+2y=4 can't provide any solution because it is essentially the same equation).

That was my question,(or me trying to see if things really are that way)

Thanks!

Comment: As far as linearly-dependent columns go, the determinant of the transpose of a matrix is equal to its determinant, so...

Comment: A singular matrix $A$ has at least one **non-zero** vector $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)^T$ such that $Ax=0$. Note that $Ax$ is just the linear combination of the columns of $A$ using the coefficients $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$. So, $Ax=0$ is exactly saying that this non-trivial linear combination is $0$. This is, the columns of $A$ a linearly dependent.

Comment: This is wrong. Take $A = 0$.

Comment: @Nicolas The columns of the matrix $0$ are linearly dependent. Any choice of not-all-zero coefficients is a linear dependence of them.

Comment: My main question is: if a matrix is not singular,then it is also possible to say that its rows are not linearly dependent?Because otherwise(singular matrix) would have linearly dependent rows and therefore no solutions.Is that concept correct?

Comment: Yes, the argument above works in both directions. If the matrix is not singular, then the only vector $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)^T$ such that $Ax=0$ is $x=0$. Since $Ax$ is just the linear combination of the columns of $A$ using the coefficients $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, then the previous statement is just saying that those columns are linearly independent.

Comment: For turning these properties into properties about the rows some people like to use the determinant, but actually you can do it simpler by looking at $y^TA$, which is a linear combination of the rows of $A$ viewed as row vectors using as coefficients the components of $y=(y_1,...,y_n)^T$. If $A$ is singular, then there is a non-zero $x$ such that $Ax=0$. Consider the row vectors $e_1^TA,...,e_n^TA$. If they were linearly independent, they would generate the whole space. Therefore, there would be $r_1e_1^TA+...+r_ne_n^TA=x$ for some scalar $r_1,...,r_n$. Taking $y=r_1e_1+...+r_ne_n$ we get ...

Comment: ... that $y^TA=x^T$. Therefore, $y^TAx=x^Tx=\|x\|^2\neq0$. But on the other hand $y^TAx=y^T(Ax)=y^T0=0$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The following are equivalent for an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ over a field $F$
(i) The rows of $A$ are linearly dependent.
(ii) The columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.
(iii) $det(A)=0$
(iv) There exists a non-trivial solution of $$A \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\.\\.\\,\\x_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\.\\.\\,\\0\end{bmatrix}$$ (iv) In the unique row-reduced echelon matrix that is row=equivalent to A, the number of leading 1's is fewer than $n.$ (v) Over an algebraically closed field containing F, there is at least one eigenvalue equal to 0 (vi) any of the above for$A^T$

Answer (score 0):

If $\det A=0$, then $\det A^\top=\det A=0$, and therefore the columns of $A$ (which are the rows of $A^\top$) will be linearly dependent too.